# Understanding proof that a contour integral along a closed path of a holomorphic function is zero

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

One of our tutorial questions in complex analysis asked us to prove that: $\int_\gamma g = 0$ for any holomorphic function $g$ on $\Omega$, and $\gamma: [a,b] \rightarrow \Omega$, which is simple and positively oriented.

The proof was really a one liner, noting that if $g$ is holomorphic on $\Omega$, then so is $g(z) = g(z)(z-a)$ for any interior point, $a$, of the path. Then we just say since $\int_\gamma g = \int_\gamma \frac{g(z)(z-a)}{z-a}dz$ **(*)**, then $\int_\gamma g = 0$ by the CIF.

Looking over the problem again I am hoping to clarify my actual understanding of why the **(*)** step is valid. I initially thought the step was trivial; I just took $g(z) = \frac{g(z)(z-a)}{z-a}$. But a moment of reflection when I reviewed the problem made me realise it's not so straightforward, because these two functions are not actually equal; the function defined by the latter has an undefined point in $\Omega$, namely at $z = a$.

**Is my new reasoning below the correct justification?**:

The functions given by $g(z)$ and $g(z)(z-a)$ differ at a single point $z=a$. Suppose that $\gamma (t_a) = a$, and note by definition $\int_\gamma g := \int_a^b g(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$.

Then since $\int_\gamma g(z)dz$ can be written as a real integral, and since $\frac{g(z)(z-a)}{z-a}$ differs at just a single point from $g(z)$, the real integral given by $\int_a^b g(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$, is equal to the contour integral $\int_\gamma \frac{g(z)(z-a)}{z-a}dz$, since the value of integrals remain unchanged for any countable difference of points in the function.

I am just wondering of this makes sense since we have to change the domains, i.e. the undefined point becomes the real number $\gamma(t_a)$ in the real integral, rather than the complex number $a$ (although I hope it is fine, and I don't see an issue currently).

Comment: $a\notin \gamma([0,1])$ (since $a$ is in the interior of the curve, not on the curve), and so the second integral is well defined and the two are equal, since $g(\gamma(t))=g(\gamma(t))(\gamma(t)-a)/(\gamma(t)-a)$.

Comment: @Caffeine Ah I see! So actually all I need to do to is to convert both the definitions into the real form, and then from the fact that $a$ is an interior point I never have to worry about the denominator being zero? Thank you!

Comment: I don't like this proof at all.  Don't you need the fact that the integral along any closed contour of a holomorphic function is zero to prove the Cauchy Integral Formula?  The proof I know for this proposition uses Greens theorem.

Comment: @DougM This was a fairly early proof in the course, before we had proved Cauchy's Integral Theorem. But at least in the exercise we were told to assume it was true.

Comment: @DougM Also I think my proof is just plain wrong because I forgot to take into account that $a$ is an interior point as caffeine pointed out...

Comment: @DougM I have never seen a proof of the elementary form of CIF without CIT, so I agree with you. However, some authors (for example, Lang) prove the general (i.e. with chains) form of CIF before the gen. form of CIT. The usual proof is due to Dixon, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @masiewpao I'm not sure of what definition you are using for the line integral, but you do not need to convert to the real one: since the line integral only depends on the value of the function on the line, and on the line the two functions are equal, so you are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you say you want to prove is false (the proofs that have appeared require more assumptions than what's given).

Let $\Omega=\{z:z\ne0\}$, $g(z)=1/z$, $[a,b]=[0,2\pi]$ and $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$. Then $$\int_\gamma g(z)\,dz=2\pi i.$$

### Note

This is a hugely important example, worth keeping in mind: (i) It explains where the Residue Theorem comes from (ii) in a sense the function $1/(z-a)$ for $a\notin\Omega$ is the only counterexample (or rather if none of those functions is a counterexample then there is no counterexample):

**Theorem.** Suppose $\gamma$ is a (smooth) closed curve in the open set $\Omega\subset\Bbb C$. TFAE:

(i) $\int_\gamma f=0$ for all $f\in H(\Omega)$.

(ii) $\int_\gamma f=0$ if $f(z)=1/(z-a)$ for some $a\in\Bbb C\setminus\Omega$.

(iii) $Ind(\gamma, a)=0$ for all $a\in\Bbb C\setminus\Omega$.

Proof: (ii) is a special case of  (i). If you write $Ind$ as an integral it's clear that (ii) and (iii) are equivalent. And CT says precisely that (iii) implies (i).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm trying to wrap my head around this. I followed caffeine's idea, so I'm not quite sure why this example comes out this way. What are the additional assumptions required? I just double checked my tutorial sheet, and there is a condition that the contour is closed which I forgot to add into my question; but in your example the path is closed anyway...

Comment: @masiewpao My idea was based on the assumptions (which, as Ullrich showed, are necessary) that $\text{int}(\gamma)\subset \Omega$ and that $\gamma$ is closed. Those are necessary to the CIF and thus I supposed you tacitly assumed those requirements.

Comment: @masiewpao It sounds like you need a different tutorial sheet! What extra assumptions are needed? Find a *book* on complex, and look up CT and CIF. (It's true if for example $\Omega$ is simply connected; more generally if $Ind(\gamma, z)=0$ for all $z\in\Bbb C\setminus \Omega$.)

Comment: @masiewpao See Edit to answer for maybe a little insight...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thank you very much! The edit is very helpful. I think this was maybe my fault for being overly pedantic; the tutorial sheet was from quite early on in the course, before we'd proved many major results. So I think the idea was to get us comfortable with using the results. Also I've realise we may have made some implicit assumptions about the convexity of $\Omega$ on our proof of CIF anyway.

Answer (score -1):

The proof I know using Green's theorem.

If $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $D$ and $\gamma$ is a closed contour on this domain $\oint_\gamma f(z)\ dz = 0$

$f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)\\
dz = dx + i\ dy\\$

$\oint_\gamma f(z)\ dz\\ = \int (u+iv)(dx + i\ dy)$

Which we multiply out and break into real and imaginary parts.

$\int u\ dx - v\ dy + i\int v\ dx + u\ dy$

Greens theorem says over any closed contour.

$\oint P\ dx + Q\ dy = \iint \left(\frac {\partial Q}{\partial x} -\frac {\partial P}{\partial y}\right) \ dx\ dy$

And if we apply it to each of the integrals above.

$\int -\left(\frac {\partial v}{\partial x} + \frac {\partial u}{\partial x}\right) \ dx \ dy + i\int \left(\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\right) \ dx \ dy$

But the Cauchy-Riemann equations say that for a holomorphic function

$\frac {\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\\
\frac {\partial v}{\partial x} = - \frac {\partial u}{\partial x}$

Making both integrals equal to zero.

Comment: Unless you are using a very general form of Green's theorem (in which case it may  be useful to state its assumptions), it is usually assumed that $\partial u,v$ are integrable, which is not given in the question (unless you prove that it is true for holomorphic functions, which is usually done by means of CIT)